# FFMPEG COLORHOLD FILTER NOT WORKING. VIDEOS WON'T PLAY

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am trying to do black and white video, while leaving just one color / color range.  I was told "ColorHold" filter can do this.  But, when I run it with different encoders; I either get a video that doesn't play.  Or one that nothing has been modified at all it seems.

This is the Command Line statement I'm running.  I know my logging isn't right.  But it still logged.  LOL.  It won't let me post my log.  Thanks.

```
ffmpeg  -i MVI_7523.MP4 -filter_complex "colorhold=color=0xE60000:similarity=1:blend=0.0"     -r 59.94     -b 60M -crf 0 output-leave-color-005.mp4 > "outputlog.txt"
```

---

Comment: Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` and check.

Comment: @Gyan I either get a video that won't play.  Plays but is all black.  Or, plays fine but has not been modified.  Using no encoder specified, h264_qsv & h264_nvenc.  Even with pix_fmt, it still gives the "ARGB" Swscaler warnings.  Also this warning...   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000027c7d971340] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 1001
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000027c7d971340] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 1001.

Comment: Add `-ignore_editlist true` before `-i`

Comment: @Gyan It turns out the warning isn't the problem.  There is little info on ColorHold filter.  And the settings are extremely sensitive.  We simply were plugging in values that cause it to ignore everything.  LOL.    This works with these super low values.  ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i MVI_3318_FINAL.mp4 -filter_complex "colorhold=color=red:similarity=0.332:blend=0.01" -vcodec h264_qsv -r 59.94 -b:v 60M -crf 0 output-leave-color-0020.mp4.  See here.  Pretty dope!  https://youtu.be/J6J2_4Bf9q4?si=sBfQv_M5-4ditHN5

Comment: @Gyan What does " -ignore_editlist true" do?  I am in learning mode, because its required to advance my business.  Thanks again.